# Can you code Firebase to check two passwords are matching in the registration form at sign up?

Tags: firebase-authentication

Need help with the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have much to do with firebase. I'm not sure what programming language and/or framework you are using, but matching password fields should occur on the client side, just like any other type of form validation you may have.